# Finding the amount of magic numbers $N$

Tags: combinatorics

Suppose $N$ is called a magic number if it is a positive integer and when you stick $N$ on the end of any positive integer, the resulting integer is divisible by $N.$ How many magic numbers are there less than $2100?$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If $\ N\,\big|\,10^rM+N\ $ for *any* positive integer $\ M\ $, where $\ 10^r\ $ is the smallest power of $\ 10\ $ exceeding $\ N\ $, what does that tell you about $\ N\ $?

Comment: N divides $10^rM,$ but how does that help?

Comment: It divides $\ 10^rM\ $ for *any* positive integer $\ M\ $, even if it's relatively prime to $\ N\ $.

Comment: I don't get what you mean. Could you elaborate?

Comment: If $\ N\ $ divides $\ 10^rM\ $ for any positive integer $\ M\ $, then it must divide $\ 10^r\ $ (take $\ M=1\ $).

Comment: So therefore $N$ must be a divisor of $10^r?$ So $N$ is a divisor of $10,100,1000,$ correct?

Comment: Or of $\ 10000\ $ as well, in your case, because $\ 2000<2100\ $.

Comment: Ah, so something like $3000$ also works? Or is it just $10^r?$

Comment: No, $\ 3000\ $ won't work.  It doesn't divide $\ 10000\ $ (or $\ 13000\ $, which you get by sticking $300$ on the end of the positive integer $1$). The only magic numbers below $\ 2100\ $ are those divisors of $\ 10000\ $ which lie in that range.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hint

$n$ can have at most $4$ digits.

Further, it is presumed that the leftmost digit of $n$ can not be $0$.

If $n$ has $k$ digits, then $n$ must be a divisor of $10^k$ such that $n \geq 10^{(k-1)}.$

Applying the prime factorization theorem against $10^k$ allows you to immediately identify all satisfying values of $n$ that correspond to a specific value for $k$.